# CAN Bus bitrate with SN65HVD230 transceiver

Tags: esp32, can-bus

I'm developing plug and play ESP32 CAN node and want to know how could I find the CAN bitrate dynamically.

Also using SN65HVD230 CAN Transceiver and developing in ESP32 IDF platform.

Regards

Comment: You can do this by routing the transceiver's RX pin to an input capture timer pin. This is more of an electronics question so it's more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/

Comment: @inimin Did you get an answer in the meantime? FWIW, I think it's possible, but to confirm, I just asked [over here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666928/auto-detecting-can-bus-bitrate).